# jQuery move and accelerate to a direction for unknown distance (smooth scroll)

Tags: jquery, smooth-scrolling

Imagine this code (simplified)

```
<img id="leftArrow"/>
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:300px">
  <img id="wideImage" style="width:1000px; position:absolute; left:0"/>
</div>
<img id="rightArrow"/>
```

that will result in something like this
[image]
<sub>(source: [aximili at home.exetel.com.au](http://home.exetel.com.au/aximili/tmp/stackoverflow-sample-scroll.jpg))</sub>

How do you make #wideImage scroll smoothly to the left when #rightArrow is hovered?

I am after something like this

```
$('#right').hover(function() {
  //On hover, accelerate #wideImage to the left
}, function() {
  //On mouse out, decelerate to stop
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sort of does it

```
$('#right').hover(function() {
  $('#wideImage').animate({ left: '-=50' }, 250, 'easeInQuad', function () {
    $('#wideImage').animate({ left: '-=600' }, 250, 'linear', function () {
      $('#wideImage').animate({ left: '-=50' }, 250, 'easeOutQuad');
    });
  });
}, function() {
  $('#wideImage').stop();
  $('#wideImage').animate({ left: '-=50' }, 250, 'easeOutQuad');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should give a look @ [this](http://www.irengba.com/codewell/)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't looking for looping but it's interesting and gave me an idea, +1

Answer (score 0):

Here is [nice tutorial](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/automatic-image-slider-w-css-jquery/) that essentially does the same thing you are trying to do (automatically too)

---

Edit: Oh, your screen shot kind of threw me off, I was thinking you wanted to scroll through multiple images, but now I see you want to pan across one very wide one?

I made [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MvRdD/7/) to answer another question, but I updated it so you could just hover over the buttons to animate the image. I hope this is more like what you wanted.

Comment: It's different, I need it to move on hover and stop on mouseout, but thanks anyway

Comment: Opps, sorry, I've updated my answer to something more like what I think you want.